# Countdown Timer displaying .php file

Tags: php, countdown

I'm using a countdown timer to show a link when the clock runs down to 0. Is there a way that I can call a .php file instead of displaying a link when the clock hits 0?

This is the code that I'm using.

```
<!--START COUNTDOWN TIMER SCRIPT-->
<br />
<script type="text/javascript">                          
    window.onload = function()
    {
        countDown('my_div1', '<a href="cdtl.html">Hello 1</a>', 720); 
    }

    function countDown(elID, output, seconds)
    {
         var elem = document.getElementById(elID),
             start = new Date().getTime(), end = start+seconds*1000,
             timer = setInterval(function() {

             var now = new Date().getTime(), timeleft = end-now, timeparts;

             if( timeleft < 0) {
                 elem.innerHTML = output;
                 clearInterval(timer);
             }
             else {
                 timeparts = [Math.floor(timeleft/60000),Math.floor(timeleft/1000)%60];
                 if( timeparts[1] < 10) timeparts[1] = "0"+timeparts[1];
                 elem.innerHTML = "Time left: "+timeparts[0]+":"+timeparts[1];
             }
         } ,250); // the lower this number, the more accurate the timer. 250 recommended 
    }
</script>

<center>
    <div id="my_div1"></div>
</center>

<!--END COUNTDOWN TIMER SCRIPT-->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, you can use

**First**, include jQuery:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>\
```

**Then**, whenever your counter is done,  call one of jQuery's ajax functions:
1) [`$('#idOfContainer').load("/path/to/your/file")`](http://api.jquery.com/load/): embeds a page dynamically inside the specified container. Use `$.load("path")` to just call the page.

2) [`$('#idOfContainer').get("/path/to/your/file")`](http://api.jquery.com/get/): calls the file using an HTTP GET request. The result is then shown inside the container specified. Use `$.get("path")` to just call the page.

3) [`$('#idOfContainer').post("/path/to/your/file")`](http://api.jquery.com/get/): calls the file using an HTTP POST request. The result is then shown inside the container specified. Use `$.post("path")` to just call the page.

Click any of the above links for more details on each command.
**Good Luck!**

Comment: jQuery load doesn't work for a file download. (which i believe the question is about)

Comment: It's not about a file download. I want to open a .php file inside of the same window.

Comment: well that's what jQuery load can do for you :)

Comment: Can you elaborate? I only know php and html not javascript.

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know if anything is not clear enough

Answer (score 0):

### update

change `elem.innerHTML = output;`

to

`document.location.href = output;`

then change

`countDown('my_div1', '<a href="cdtl.html">Hello 1</a>', 720);`

to

`countDown('my_div1', 'cdtl.html', 720);`

Comment: and then where do I put the link? I'm bad at javascript.

Comment: Man, I gave you the wrong script that I was using lol Can you tell me how to do it in this one?

Comment: the same window as in without refreshing the page?

Comment: Like how can I get the php file to open in an iframe or display on the same page without opening a new window?

Comment: change `document.location.href = output;` to `document.getElementById('yourIFRAMEID').location.href = output;`

Comment: where do I put that iframe at?

Comment: Sorry I'm like a complete newb at javascript. Only good at php and html. I see what is it but don't know how to apply it.

Comment: the comments is getting to long.. i can try to show u how to do it on a jsfiddle (put some of the code in there)

Comment: Okay, I get what you're saying... but how do I apply this to the code I already have?